# WPF Window Real-Time Preview

Tags: wpf, preview

I have a window in WPF which shows some media contents. This content contains WPF animations, videos, images etc. My need is to create a real-time preview for this window. Can I create this using WPF?

Look at below image, my requirement is to show preview of Window2 in preview area in Window1.

[alt text http://www.dailycoding.com/FileSharing/WPF_Preview.png](http://www.dailycoding.com/FileSharing/WPF_Preview.png)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can.
Take a look at `System.Windows.Media.VisualBrush` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualbrush.aspx).